# The last number is being displayed out of specified range

Tags: php, arrays, range

I recently started taking classes on PHP and I came across a weird bug on my code which I just don't understand...

I'm probably just not seeing the solution right now and so I decided to post it here so anybody experienced can help me out instead of waiting for monday to ask a teacher.

What I basically want is to create an array that will take 10 numbers ranging from 1-49 and then create another array which will take these values, shuffle them and randomly take them out one by one to display the full array.

I did this for 2 possible arrays but the last array, the last number is not being displayed with my 1-49 range and is crossing that range.

My code is as follows:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['views'];
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        $array = range(1, 49);
        $numbers = array();


        for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
            shuffle($array);
            $numbers[] = $array[0]; 
            unset($array[0]); 
        }
        print ('Primeiro numero <br/>');
        print_r($numbers[0]);
        print(', ');
        print_r($numbers[1]);
        print(', ');
        print_r($numbers[2]);
        print(', ');
        print_r($numbers[3]);
        print(', ');
        print_r($numbers[4]);
        print(', ');
        print_r($numbers[5]);
        print(', ');
        print_r($numbers[6]);
        print(', ');
        print_r($numbers[7]);
        print(', ');
        print_r($numbers[8]);
        print(', ');
        print_r($numbers[9]);



        for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
            shuffle($array);
            $numbers2[] = $array[0];
            unset($array[0]); 
        }

        print ('<br><br>');

        print ('Segundo numero <br/>');
        print_r($numbers2[0]);
        print(', ');
        print_r($numbers2[1]);
        print(', ');
        print_r($numbers2[2]);
        print(', ');
        print_r($numbers2[3]);
        print(', ');
        print_r($numbers2[4]);
        print(', ');
        print_r($numbers2[5]);
        print(', ');
        print_r($numbers2[6]);
        print(', ');
        print_r($numbers2[7]);
        print(', ');
        print_r($numbers2[8]);
        print(', ');
        print_r($numbers2[9]);



        if ($_GET["destroy"] == "destroy")
            session_destroy();
        else {
            if ($_SESSION['views'] > 0) {
                $_SESSION['views'] ++;
            } else {
                $_SESSION['views'] = 1;
            }
            echo $_SESSION['views'];
        }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

If someone helps me finding the problem with the last number from the 2nd array being displayed wrong that would be a huge help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The last number is the concatenation of the last number of the `$numbers2` array and the counter `$_SESSION['views']`... Instead of `echo $_SESSION['views'];` use something like `echo '<br><br>' . $_SESSION['views'];`

Comment: Thank you very much, I knew the solution was simple and I was not seeing it ...